# The games created for Android in Adobe flash are crashing without giving an error on the device

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am building a simple game in flash for android. I am using **AS3**. After publishing the APK and trying it on the device, the game crashes automatically. and it doesn't even use a lot of resources. I tried everything but still the same problem.

I also tried publishing the apk with and without the Adobe Air Embedded.
Can Anyone tell me why is this happening?

And I am using an accelerometer. And the Frame rate is 24.The Device is Redmi note 4g.

below is the code for two classes.

```js
package 
{
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.AccelerometerEvent;
 import flash.events.Event;
 import flash.events.MouseEvent;
 import flash.events.TimerEvent;
 import flash.events.TouchEvent;
 import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;
 import flash.utils.Timer;

 public class laduCatch extends MovieClip
 {
  public var rat:MovieClip;
  //declaring the array for ladus
  private var laduarr:Array;
  
  public var score:Number = 0;
  public var missed:Number = 0;
  
  public function laduCatch()
  {

   laduarr = new Array();

   //TIMER DECLARATION AND INITIALISATION 

   var ladutimer:Timer = new Timer(500);

   ladutimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,addladu);
   ladutimer.start();

   //ADDING LADU;

   function addladu(e:TimerEvent):void
   {
    var ladu1 : ladu = new ladu();
    stage.addChild(ladu1);
    laduarr.push(ladu1);
    trace(laduarr.length);
   }

   function gameloop(event:Event):void
   {
    laduoutofstage();
   }
   
   function laduoutofstage():void
   {

    for (var i:int = 0; i < laduarr.length; i++)
    {

     var currladu:ladu = laduarr[i];

     if (currladu.y > stage.stageHeight)
     {
      //trace("ladu out of the screen");
      laduarr.splice(i, 1);
      //trace("ladu out and removed from array");
      //trace(laduarr.length);
      currladu.destroyladu();
      missed++;
      //trace("Ladu missed");
      //trace(missed);
      missedScore.text = String(missed);
      //trace("ladu destroyed sucsessfully");
     }
     else if (rat.hitTestObject(currladu))
     {
      laduarr.splice(i, 1);
      //trace(laduarr.length);
      currladu.destroyladu();
      //trace("ladu collected");
      score++;
      //trace(score);
      collectedScore.text = String(score);

     }


    }
   }

   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);

   //ACCELEROMETER LOGIC 
   function ratmove(event:Event):void
   {

    var sen : Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();

    sen.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, update);
    sen.setRequestedUpdateInterval(4);

    function update(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
    {
     //trace(rat.x);
     //trace(rat.y);
     rat.x -=(event.accelerationX*2);
     //rat.y +=(event.accelerationY*2);

     if (rat.x < 20)
     {
      rat.x = 20;
     }
     else if (rat.x>stage.stageWidth-20)
     {
      rat.x = stage.stageWidth - 20;
     }

    }

   }


   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, ratmove);

  }

 }

}
```

```js
package 
{
 import flash.display.MovieClip;
 import flash.events.Event;
 
 public class ladu extends MovieClip 
 {
  
  public function ladu() 
  {
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,init);
   this.stop();
   
  }
  
  public function init(e:Event):void
  {
   this.y = -20;
   this.x = randomRange(0, stage.stageWidth);
   moveladu(); 
   
  }
  
  public function moveladu():void
  {
   addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, laduloop);
  }
  
  public function laduloop(e:Event):void
  {
   
   this.y += 32;
   
  }
  
  public function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
  {
   return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
  }
  
  public function destroyladu():void
  {
   parent.removeChild(this);
   removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, laduloop);
  }
  
 }

}
```

Comment: What happens with your debug build?

Comment: So you share no code, give no errors, and now asking **why is "this" happening**.. Let me ask the magic ball :)

Comment: there you go u have the code and there's no error in the code. you won't need the magic ball. now plz help if you can.

Comment: @e4c5 the game will open on the device will sort of lag and then crash without generating any type of log or error or warning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate your functions instead of nesting them inside each others. Why:

You set Event Listener to run ratmove() on every frame, but inside ratmove function you also create new accelerometer each time and assign event listener for it, and this happens again and again on every frame, so I guess eventually it will just crash.

I would take all functions from the constructor and keep them separated to avoid this. Structure would look somehow like this:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.AccelerometerEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.sensors.Accelerometer;
import flash.utils.Timer;

public class laduCatch extends MovieClip
{
    public var rat:MovieClip;
    //declaring the array for ladus
    private var laduarr:Array;

    public var score:Number = 0;
    public var missed:Number = 0;

    public function laduCatch()
    {
        laduarr = new Array();

        //TIMER DECLARATION AND INITIALISATION 
        var ladutimer:Timer = new Timer(500);
        ladutimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,addladu);
        ladutimer.start();
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);
        ratmove(); //CALL THIS ONLY ONCE HERE since it will add eventlistener for accelerometer
    }

    public function addladu(e:TimerEvent):void
    {
        var ladu1 : ladu = new ladu();
        stage.addChild(ladu1);
        laduarr.push(ladu1);
        trace(laduarr.length);
    }

    public function gameloop(event:Event):void
    {
        laduoutofstage();
    }

    public function laduoutofstage():void
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < laduarr.length; i++)
        {

            var currladu:ladu = laduarr[i];

            if (currladu.y > stage.stageHeight)
            {
                //trace("ladu out of the screen");
                laduarr.splice(i, 1);
                //trace("ladu out and removed from array");
                //trace(laduarr.length);
                currladu.destroyladu();
                missed++;
                //trace("Ladu missed");
                //trace(missed);
                missedScore.text = String(missed);
                //trace("ladu destroyed sucsessfully");
            }
            else if (rat.hitTestObject(currladu))
            {
                laduarr.splice(i, 1);
                //trace(laduarr.length);
                currladu.destroyladu();
                //trace("ladu collected");
                score++;
                //trace(score);
                collectedScore.text = String(score);
            }
        }
    }

    //ACCELEROMETER LOGIC 
    public function ratmove():void
    {
        var sen : Accelerometer = new Accelerometer();
        sen.addEventListener(AccelerometerEvent.UPDATE, update);
        sen.setRequestedUpdateInterval(4);
    }

    public function update(event:AccelerometerEvent):void
    {
        //trace(rat.x);
        //trace(rat.y);
        rat.x -=(event.accelerationX*2);
        //rat.y +=(event.accelerationY*2);

        if (rat.x < 20)
        {
            rat.x = 20;
        }
        else if (rat.x>stage.stageWidth-20)
        {
            rat.x = stage.stageWidth - 20;
        }

    }

}

}
```